# Chosing "input" in an AND (&&) and OR (||) list of commands

Tags: bash, shell, input

I have to find a way to have my script read from one of these three options:

- a file argument
- standard input
- a previously established environment variable

Here's what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

key=$1
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$2" ] && input="$2" || [ -f "$INPUT" ] && input="$INPUT" || input="-"
echo $input
```

Only the environment variable refuses to work, the rest works fine.
I've tried using the `export INPUT="pathnametofile"` before but it doesn't make any difference, I end up with the shell asking me to enter info as if I called on `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem in your script

Your attemp is not working due to the way the shell processes a [Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists):

> ‘&&’ and ‘||’ have equal precedence.
>
> AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.

Your sentence:

```
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$2" ] && input="$2" || [ -f "$INPUT" ] && input="$INPUT" || input="-"
```

does the same as follows:

```
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$2" ] && input="$2"
[ $? -eq 0 ] || [ -f "$INPUT" ]
[ $? -eq 0 ] && input="$INPUT"
[ $? -eq 0 ] || input="-"
```

Now yo may see why your unexpected behaviour.

---

#### A better attempt [grouping commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

```
{ [ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$2" ] && input="$2"; } || { [ -f "$INPUT" ] && input="$INPUT"; } || input="-"
```

Now, due to precedence, the first group is not needed at all:

```
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$2" ] && input="$2" || { [ -f "$INPUT" ] && input="$INPUT"; } || input="-"
```

Furthermore, unless you have set the positional parameters by hand, you can remove the first  check (after all, if `$2` is emtpy, `-f ""` fails the same).

```
[ -f "$2" ] && input="$2" || { [ -f "$INPUT" ] && input="$INPUT"; } || input="-"
```

---

#### An alternative with the `if` [conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

```
if [ -f "$2" ]; then
    input=$2
elif [ -f "$INPUT" ]; then
    input=$INPUT
fi
echo "${input:=-}"
```

Comment: Glenn was first, and correct, but to go to the trouble to link to the bash manual, that is a `5-star` answer - well done!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, an absolutely impeccable answer, my thanks.

Answer (score 0):

untested, but you'll probably have better luck with `if` commands, and test that the variable is not empty:

```
if [ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$2" ]; then
    input="$2"
elif [ -n "$INPUT" -a -f "$INPUT" ]; then
    input="$INPUT"
else
    input="-"
fi
```